# How to build CEF with third party utilities including swiftshader and node and node_modules on windows 10with Visual studio 2017 installed

Tags: c++, c, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build CEF from source on windows 10, with Visual Studio 2017 installed. And following the steps on the official CEF repository at

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart

at the 8th step, I was trying the build for Release config. instead of debugging, so I used the following command instead:

```
ninja -C out\Release_GN_x86 cef
```

But I have following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'f:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\third_party\node\node_modules\polymer-bundler\lib\bin\polymer-bundler'
```

noting that I had to install node.exe manually after reading the bash file:

```
F:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\third_party\node\update_node_binaries
```

I search for bash file in the `dep_tools` folder and tried to run update_node_binaries from bash, but it says nom not found

Is there any initializing command that should be called to install all third-party utilities for chromium and CEF before building the code ?

An other Error Keeps poping every time I executed the build command:

```
ninja -C out\Release_GN_x86 cef
```

The Error:

```
[269/21980] RC obj/third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL/libEGL/swiftshader_libEGL/libEGL.res
FAILED: obj/third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL/libEGL/swiftshader_libEGL/libEGL.res
F:/code/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_13_chromium7_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/toolchain/win/tool_wrapper.py rc-wrapper environment.x86 rc.exe /nologo -DUSE_AURA=1 -DNO_TCMALLOC -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD "-DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"356356-1\"" -D_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_NODISCARD -D_LIBCPP_NO_AUTO_LINK -D__STD_C -D_CRT_RAND_S -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_ATL_NO_OPENGL -D_WINDOWS -DCERT_CHAIN_PARA_HAS_EXTRA_FIELDS -DPSAPI_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_SECURE_ATL -D_USING_V110_SDK71_ -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOMINMAX -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x0A000003 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DNOMINMAX -D_WINDLL -DNO_SANITIZE_FUNCTION= -DANGLE_DISABLE_TRACE -DEGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DEGLAPI= -I../../third_party/swiftshader/include -I../../third_party/swiftshader/src -I../../third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL -I../.. -Igen /foobj/third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL/libEGL/swiftshader_libEGL/libEGL.res ../../third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL/libEGL/libEGL.rc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\build\toolchain\win\rc\rc.py", line 192, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "f:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\build\toolchain\win\rc\rc.py", line 188, in main
    return RunRc(preprocessed_output, is_utf8, flags)
  File "f:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\build\toolchain\win\rc\rc.py", line 173, in RunRc
    p = subprocess.Popen(rc_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "F:\code\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_13_chromium7_bin\python\bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "F:\code\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_13_chromium7_bin\python\bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[271/21980] CXX obj/third_party/swiftshader/src/OpenGL/libEGL/swiftshader_libEGL/libEGL.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: These are compilation error and problem in resolving dependencies. I would suggest rechecking system variable and steps.

Comment: @ErikNielsen I followed the steps literally, so as the documentation states I should have setup my environment correctly to build the code, I am trying to build the code agin and will update the question with the full error message

Comment: Running from node.js console solved that problem for me.